# Difference between = and := in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, colon-equals

in `MySQL` what is the difference between these two command?

They work perfectly and the result is always the same:

```
set @numRecords = (select count(*) from config);

set @numRecords := (select count(*) from config);
```

Thanks
Davide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual, [section 10.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> For SET, either = or := can be used as the assignment operator.
>
> You can also assign a value to a user variable in statements other
>   than SET. In this case, the assignment operator must be := and not =
>   because the latter is treated as the comparison operator = in non-SET
>   statements

Answer (score 3):

"=" is ambiguous and could be a comparison operator. ":=" is always interpreted as an assignment operator. This information can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html .